# Changing datatype of a property

Tags: c#, properties

I have a Class A which has an object of my another class B. Class B has a property which can be of any data type. Here is my

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    object value;
    int max;
    string dataType;
    bool nullable;
    bool isKey;
    bool isIdentity;
}
```

Now another class B is like this

```
public class B : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public B()
    {
       A objA=new A();
    }
}
```

Now, in my code, I will instantiate object of B, and somehow I want to override the property VALUE of objA to some datatype for example string or int. I don't want to typecast it in my code, I want to typecast it in Class B, as I will be knowing its datatype in class B.

Also, I would appreciate if someone can tell me a better way to do this.

Thanks & Regards,
Bhushan

Comment: is `objA` a field in B?  If not, then it is going to be out of scope when the B constructor is finished.

Answer (score 4):

You can create generic class A and select its type when instantiating in B:

```
public class A<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    T value;
    int max;
    string dataType;
    bool nullable;
    bool isKey;
    bool isIdentity;
}

public class B : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public B()
    {
        A<int> objA = new A<int>();
    }
}
```